# Ansible default filter

Tags: python, ansible, yaml

How can i force default filter try to find value of variable untill value will not found?

in my code **{{netplanadditionalip4 | default('netplanadditionalip3') }}"** print **netplanadditionalip3** if there is not variable, but I need default filter try netplanadditionalip2 netplanadditionalip1 etc, is it possible?

```
- name: debug1
  debug:
    msg: "{{netplanadditionalip1 | default ('ansible_host')}}"

- name: debug2
  debug:
    msg: "{{netplanadditionalip2 | default('netplanadditionalip1') }}"

- name: debug3
  debug:
    msg: "{{netplanadditionalip3 | default('netplanadditionalip2') }}"

- name: debug4
  debug:
    msg: "{{netplanadditionalip4 | default('netplanadditionalip3') }}"
```

Comment: So you want to test first with `netplanadditionalip3`, then `netplanadditionalip2` and `netplanadditionalip1` sequentially if the previous is not working?

Comment: yeah, you are right!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about something like:

```
---
- name: Default Filter Sequence
  hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  gather_facts: true

  vars:

    netplanadditionalip1: 10.100.10.1
    netplanadditionalip2: 10.100.10.2
    netplanadditionalip3: 10.100.10.3

  tasks:

  - name: Fact of Ansible Host
    set_fact:
      my_host: "{{ ansible_host | default () }}"

  - name: debug1
    debug:
      msg: "{{ netplanadditionalip1 | default(my_host) }}"

  - name: debug2
    debug:
      msg: "{{ netplanadditionalip2 | default(item) }}"
    with_items:
      - "{{ netplanadditionalip1 | default( my_host ) }}"

  - name: debug3
    debug:
      msg: "{{ netplanadditionalip3 | default(item) }}"
    with_items:
      - "{{ netplanadditionalip2 | default( netplanadditionalip1 ) | default( my_host ) }}"

  - name: debug4
    debug:
      msg: "{{ netplanadditionalip4 | default(item) }}"
    with_items:
      - "{{ netplanadditionalip3 | default( netplanadditionalip2 ) | default( netplanadditionalip1 ) | default( my_host ) }}"
```

Comment: thx you very much, you helped me.  I just made a few default filter without set_fact  `{{ netplanadditionalip5 | default(netplanadditionalip4) | default( netplanadditionalip3 ) | default( netplanadditionalip2 ) | default( netplanadditionalip1 ) | default( ansible_host )}}`

Comment: can not vote because of `Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score.`